# User systemd PulseAudio service

Tags: arch-linux, users, systemd, pulseaudio, d-bus

Not much else to this question: I would like to know what I need to create a PulseAudio systemd service to be run with `systemd --user`.

I've tried a few different things, including various user services from Google, but I can't get it set up just right between dbus and everything else required for it.

**Update:** It seems to work ok with graphical sessions, but I'm still having some inconsistancy with dbus when logging in through console.  But PulseAudio is starting rather reliably, so I'm not overly concerned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just a guess but something like this in a file `systemd/user/pulseaudio.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=PulseAudio Sound System
Before=sound.target

[Service]
BusName=org.pulseaudio.Server
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=session.target
```

I found this in a [github repo](https://github.com/Keruspe/system-config) which had additional files related to systemd setup.

The author of that repo, also wrote up on his blog this post: [systemd as a session manager](http://www.imagination-land.org/posts/2013-01-01-systemd-as-a-session-manager.html). This post details how to make use of the files in the repo.

Incidentally the files in the repo go here, `${HOME}/.config/systemd/user/`.

Comment: Using this as the pulseaudio.service, plus dbus.service & dbus.socket from [here](https://github.com/sofar/user-session-units/tree/master/units/user), I finally got it to work! It spits out errors if I try to stop it, but I figure I probably won't be stopping PulseAudio anyway.  Thanks a ton!